# Summing specific values within an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, sum, range, conditional-statements

I am trying to do operations with values that I have added into an array.

step 1:

Loaded a xls file with xlrd library and created an array.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAmPx.png

Here is the code.

```
import xlrd

datafile = "data.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(datafile)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, col) 
            for col in range(sheet.ncols)] 
                for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
```

I would like to sum all the values within a column
   `print (data[1][1])
    print (data[2][1])
    print (data[3][1])
    print (data[4][1])
    print (data[5][1])`

summ all the way to I (data[I][1]) ??

like summing all the rows for the same column,

i have tried to do sum data[1] but this sums all the values for the same row (like an horizontal sum of the values...) and I am trying to do a vertical sum)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> sum(data[i][1] for i in range(len(data)))
12 # 2 + 4 + 6
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's `np.sum()` to sum along or down the axes of a matrix, producing a vector of sums, as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [ [1,2],[3,4],[5,6] ]

>>> np.sum(data,0)

array([ 9, 12]) # Summing down the matrix (axis 0)

>>> np.sum(data,1)

array([ 3,  7, 11]) # Summing along the matrix (axis 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for taking the time.
@C.B
I got a syntax error.
@StackG, thanks, that exactly what I was looking for.
However, I found another way to do it.

import xlrd.
'print (sheet.col_values(1, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=100))'